# Is doubt a cognitive state of belief, an emotional state, or both?

Tags: doubt

Is it possible to internally find no reason to doubt something yet still feel doubt? Is it possible to find plenty of reason to doubt something yet not feel any doubt?

Bertrand Russell suggested that doubt "suggests a vacillation, an alternate belief and disbelief." But this seems to assume that doubt is purely cognitive, which would in turn assume that it is not possible to have a lack of belief in something cognitively yet still feel doubt as an emotion.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Both. One can intuitively doubt and exploit the anxiety of unwanted dissonance, or one can reason as skeptic to radically undermine the existence of knowledge.

Comment: You should ask what our feelings are too.

Comment: i think you should add 'affect' for the hard of feeling lol. why not mood? how about comportment ha

Answer (score 1):

i think that BR told not about emotional doubts. That mean that emotional doubts are not about BR told. "Emotional doubts" are not ever real doubts.

For example doubts of jealousy based not on disbelief in love(for example), not on the reaction on assumed partner's flirt. That mean that doubts begets emotional statuses or ect. and other fantasies about unfaithfulness. Not said words to another begets distrust, but doubts(in something foundation) begets distrusting view point that supported by emotions. Lots of emotions beget the affect status, when doubting person doesn't able to see what directly calls the doubt effect - because emotional hormones(emotional statuses) they deprive him of the opportunity to soberly assess
situation.

Also a man may has calm doubts, with low emotions, but it is still can be hard to find their cause. For example to doubt that the God is exist. Someone is not crying about it, but has self doubt. Or crying, but not always, sometimes he is calm, but still in doubts, maybe more then in crying.

*and here you are close to answer a question what are emotions and why are you use them, and why BR relied on them less then nowaday humans do.

Answer (score 0):

Doubt is *cognitive*, si, and as mentioned, *emotive* as well.  It's always a good idea to investigate the different aspects of anything (that might concern us) and *dubium* (doubt) is just such a thing.

Many great thinkers have studied doubt in, from the looks of it, great detail. There's a large corpus of philosophical musings on this subject - but a mouseclick away from the eager beaver.

As for Bertrand Russell's beliefs on doubt, he is correct ... to the extent one can be on the *nature* of this *cognitive-emotive beast* we call *doubt*. Bertrand Russell had no palpable *transcendental beliefs* last I checked but that's not surprising; nevertheless, he was a *h. sapiens*, one of the best (mental) specimens evolution has produced (youtube his interviews if you have any questions).